# How to go around QGIS's same CRS restriction when doing spatial queries?

Tags: qgis

As someone who used ArcGIS pretty frequently and then moved to QGIS, I find this restriction to be pretty annoying.

Normally it would be possible to convert everything to the same coordinate system but the problem is that I'm working with WFS layers and QGIS goes absolutely bonkers when I try to change the CRS (only way is to ctrl alt del and end task)

I honestly thought that the select by location tool was broken since every selection I've attempted simply would not work.

Is there a work around this?

Comment: I don't think the **Select by attributes** tool uses spatial queries, do you mean another tool like **Select by location**?

Comment: Can't you read WFS with your target srsName?

Comment: No, the thing just gets stuck on loading. My work around was to save it in another layer which took a lot of time because over 50k features. There has to be something else there, this was so easy to do in Arc